# Decode string into a list of integers

Tags: javascript

How do I decode a string whose length is multiple of 4 into a list of 32-bit integers in javascript?

Something that does the equivalent of struct.unpack('>16I, 16characterstring) in python.
I'm okay with using common external libraries. I am looking for something clean and which hopefully avoids bit-shifting and manipulation.

Example,

```
"deadbeef" -> (1684365668, 1650812262)

"dead" -> [1684365668]
"beef" -> [1650812262]
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? Can you give an example of the input (string), and the expected output (bytes, maybe hex bytes)?

Comment: Added example in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach - doesn't need the character types. Uses multiplication as a bit shifting technique. I wrote it so it will still work when str.length is not a multiple of 4 - but you did in fact state in your question that it would be...

Note - I did not try to do "clever coding" - so I made sure things were explicitly assigned, one statement at a time, ... You can probably come up with a more compact way to achieve the same thing. This should give you some inspiration though.

```
function stringToIntArray(str) {
  var l = Math.ceil(str.length/4);  // not needed if you are sure it's a multiple of 4
  var opArray = new Array(l);       // known length - miniscule speed advantage?
  var ii=0, jj=0, charCounter=0;    // ii loops over 4-char word-of-interest
                                    // jj counts elements in the output array
                                    // charCounter points to the current character
  opArray[0]=0;
  while( charCounter < str.length ) {
    ii = charCounter % 4;     // count 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3...
    opArray[jj] *= 256;                 // left shift 8 bits
    opArray[jj] += str.charCodeAt(charCounter);  // add next code
    if(ii==3) {
      opArray[++jj]=0; 
      }
    charCounter++;
  }
  return opArray;
}

var myval = stringToIntArray("deadbeef");
alert("'dead' turns into " + myval[0] + "\n'beef' turns into " + myval[1]);
```

Output:

```
'dead' turns into 1684365668
'beef' turns into 1650812262
```

Result is as expected; doesn't require HTML5 compliant browser; and is big endian.

Answer (score 1):

How about https://github.com/vjeux/jParser - This library looks promising.

Comment: That is nice. Heavy for my use case but that's what I will use if I can't find anything simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This uses HTML5 typed arrays so it does require a [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=typedarrays)

```
function strToU32(str) {
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    str.split("").forEach(function(char,i){ 
        var code = char.charCodeAt(0); 
        u8[i] = code;
    })

    var u32 = new Uint32Array(u8.buffer);
    return u32;
}
```

Usage:

```
var integers = strToU32("abcdefgh");
console.log(integers[0]); // returns 1684234849
console.log(integers[1]); // returns 1751606885
```

Comment: I think your conversion is little endian and I want big endian.

Comment: Worse, I don't think endianess for this operation is defined in HTML5